# How to serialize instruction buffer for an Anchor program

Tags: anchor, serialization, client

Given the following Anchor instruction :

```
pub fn create_joke(ctx: Context<CreateJokeCtx>, joke_content: String)
-> ProgramResult {
   ...
}
```

How to find the borsch schema and serialize the instruction buffer `data: instructionBuffer` properly for an anchor program **without anchor libs**?

```
 const sendJokeInstrux = new TransactionInstruction({
    programId: programAddress,
    data: instructionBuffer,
    keys: [
       ...
    ],
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

## Two ways

#### 1. Using The Program Source

We can use anchor cli with [anchor expand](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#expand) (which would probably require you to use the nightly version of rust) `rustup default nightly`

`anchor expand` will unroll the code that is generated by the anchor macros so you can see all the final rust code generated. In the generated program you can find the below information:

```
Sha256("<namespace>::<rust-identifier>")[..8],
```

With this comment:

```
Each method in an anchor program is uniquely defined by a namespace
and a rust identifier where the namespace can be one of three types.
1) "global" for a regular instruction [...]
```

So the instruction buffer is:

```
import { sha256 } from "js-sha256";

const anchorIxName = 'global' + ':' + 'create_joke';
const ixBuffer = Buffer.from(sha256.digest(anchorIxName)).slice(0, 8)
```

#### 2. Without The Source

First find the IDL of the program with:

- [Solaneyes](https://www.solaneyes.com/address/HZy4kyk53Zsrzgv84fuRmuXFNar9VAyJmqwVZtK1iEVy)
- [anchor fetch idl](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#idl-fetch)

Looking at the anchor typescript lib we can find this code:

```
function sighash(nameSpace: string, ixName: string): Buffer {
  let name = snakeCase(ixName);
  let preimage = `${nameSpace}:${name}`;
  return Buffer.from(sha256.digest(preimage)).slice(0, 8);
}
```

#### TLDR

Final code for the instruction buffer + a string argument

**Anchor**

```
create_joke(ctx: Context<CreateJokeCtx>, joke_content: String)
```

**JS Side**

```
// Craft the InstructionBuffer with Arg
const anchorIxName = 'global' + ':' + 'create_joke';
const ixBuffer = Buffer.from(sha256.digest(anchorIxName)).slice(0, 8)

// a String is a Vec<u8>
// a Borsch String is represented in bytes by [len + array]
const string_u8vec = new TextEncoder().encode(joke)
const string_u8vec_length = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(new BN(string_u8vec.length).toArray("le", 4)));

const instructionBuffer = Buffer.concat([
   ixBuffer,            // namespace+method_name
   string_u8vec_length, // the length of the string
   string_u8vec         // the string itself
])


// Craft the createJokeInstruction
const sendJokeInstrux = new TransactionInstruction({
  programId: programAddress,
  data: instructionBuffer,
  keys : [
    ...
  ]
})
```