# Call program instruction using solana/web3

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, instructions, node.js

Is it possible to call a program instruction using Web3?

I need to create the TransactionInstruction and sign the transaction manually and send the raw transaction to the blockchain.

The program instruction accepts 2 parameters and stores them in an account.

Something similar to this (using anchor to create the program):

```
#[account]
pub struct Person {
    pub city: String,
    pub country: String,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SavePerson<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 64 + 64)]
    pub person_account: Account<'info, Person>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// function
pub fn save_person(ctx: Context<SavePerson>, city: String, country: String) -> Result<()> {
        let person_account = &mut ctx.accounts.person_account;
        person_account.city = city;
        person_account.country = country;
        Ok(())
    }
```

I am able to test this using anchor. Used the anchor's program rpc call and I was able to execute the instruction

```
program.rpc.savePrice(
  'chennai',
  'india', {
    accounts: {
      personAccount: personAccount.publicKey,
      user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    },
    signers: [personAccount],
  }
);
```

I am trying to call this using web3js like this:

```
new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: keys,
    programId: new PublicKey(programId),
    data: Buffer.from(params, 'utf8'),
  });
```

This works if the params is a string, I need to pass 2 parameters in the data.
Is it possible?

Comment: This might help you https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-to-serialize-instruction-buffer-for-an-anchor-program